# Link to access the app on App Store from within the app doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I try to access the app page on the App Store app I keep getting errors and the code keeps failing. I apparently tried everything that worked for other people but I keep getting those errors. The feedback message I get on the console is this: "-canOpenURL: failed for URL..."

It shows the error as this one: (OSStatus error -10814.)

When searching about this error on the www.OSStatus.com to look up Apple API errors, the feedback I get is this: "No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.", what doesn't make sense because I have my app published.

Here is the link to the app on the app store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adopets-adopt-a-pet-now/id1211076909?ls=1&mt=8

Here is a copy of the code I'm using:

```
    let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/1211076909?mt=8")!

    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)

    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Didn't Apple introduce a requirement that you add it to your `Info.plist` when trying to open other application URLs?

Comment: Why not use `SKStoreProductViewController` instead of launching the store in a browser?

Comment: @rmaddy, I wish I could remember why I don't use it. I can't remember. But there was a specific reason - maybe something dealing with App Store access (as in if WiFi or cell signal not available). But I found - with a notable exception to the above code which I'll post as an answer in a moment - using the browser to be more stable of a way. YMMV.

Comment: I guess a final comment, because this question is now marked as a duplicate - which I don't 100% agree on. Move your code - which does work - into an `if` statement. `if let url = URL(string: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/1211076909?mt=8"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)`. If this is true, open the URL. If not, notify the user that you can't.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem was the fact that I was trying to access my App's App Store page through the Xcode simulator, but the truth is that it actually doesn't have one.

When trying to run the code on a real device (iPhone 7 Plus), everything worked fine.

Comment: I just commented on your question, alluding to posting an answer. I think there's a better way to code things. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this url instead. It works within an app that I made a year ago:

`URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1211076909")`